# Instagram API only returning data with self

Tags: php, curl, instagram, instagram-api

I am implementing Instagram API. It is returning data for my own user only by self keyword. What should i do to get data from other users who visit my site.

Works:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Does not work

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/ABC_USER/?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

My full code is something like this.

```
$result = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN");
 $result = json_decode($result);
  print_r($result);

function fetchData($url){
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  if(curl_error($ch))
{
echo curl_error($ch);
}
return $result;
curl_close($ch);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{user-id}` should be an `id`, not `username`.

It is usually a number, try this, it will work:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/3/?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

(if u want to find user-id for a username, use the user search API to search a username, then get the user-id, and then use it in the above API)